# Adding new paths to D3 Globe

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working on an implementation of a D3 Globe. I am trying to add paths to the globe when the user clicks a button, but this is not proving successful. If I add all paths at once there is no issue, but if I try to add them after a trigger event then it fails. My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/b6xvj76e/1/. I don't think there is an issue with the JSON, as it pops up in the console as expected.

The bit of the script that fails can be found right at the bottom of the fiddle. I paste it below for ease of reference:

```
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
  data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "path1"
      },
      "year": "2010",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": "[[[116.4551,40.2539],[117.5977,44.3408],[116.4551,40.2539]]]"
      },
      "id": "RML"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "path2"
      },
      "year": "2010",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": "[[[116.4551,40.2539],[122.3438,41.0889],[116.4551,40.2539]]]"
      },
      "id": "RML"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "path3"
      },
      "year": "2010",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": "[[[116.4551,40.2539],[105.9961,37.3096],[116.4551,40.2539]]]"
      },
      "id": "RML"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "path4"
      },
      "year": "2010",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": "[[[116.4551,40.2539],[109.5996,35.6396],[116.4551,40.2539]]]"
      },
      "id": "RML"
    }]}



  console.log(data);
  var svg = d3.select("#body");


  flows = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", clip)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d.properties.name.split(' ').join('_')
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are three:

1) Your JSON structure has a problem: the arrays are specified in string format, thus causing an error when used by the `clip` function.

2) You are binding the `data` object directly, when you should instead binding `data.features` which is the array which contains the four paths you need to create.

3) The selection will select the already existing paths for countries. You can avoid this by adding a class to the new paths. For example, classing them as `flow`.

4) The flows paths are declared inside the scope of their rendering function, therefore they cannot be updated on the refresh function.

Here's your code with the three fixes:

```
$("#clickMe").click(function () {
    // 1) Arrays: Fixed arrays for coordinates so they are not serialized in a string
    var data = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "path1"
                },
                "year": "2010",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[116.4551, 40.2539], [117.5977, 44.3408], [116.4551, 40.2539]]]
                },
                "id": "RML"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "path2"
                },
                "year": "2010",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[116.4551, 40.2539], [122.3438, 41.0889], [116.4551, 40.2539]]]
                },
                "id": "RML"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "path3"
                },
                "year": "2010",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[116.4551, 40.2539], [105.9961, 37.3096], [116.4551, 40.2539]]]
                },
                "id": "RML"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "path4"
                },
                "year": "2010",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [[[116.4551, 40.2539], [109.5996, 35.6396], [116.4551, 40.2539]]]
                },
                "id": "RML"
            }
        ]
    };

    console.log(data);

    var svg = d3.select("#body");

    // 3) Selection: Add a class to avoid collision with existing paths
    // 4) Using var declared outside so it can be used on the update function
    flows = svg.selectAll("path.flow")
        // 2) Data binding: Bind the features property instead, which is an array
        .data(data.features);

    // 3) Enter nodes: When appending them, class them as flow so they keep separated
    flows.enter().append("svg:path")
        .classed("flow", true)
        .attr("d", clip)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            return d.properties.name.split(' ').join('_')
        });
});
```

Now it works, but I still cannot see the added paths on the globe. The `path` elements are for sure appended to the DOM of the `svg` element, though, which solves your initial problem ;)

**- UPDATE -**

As indicated on the comments, the added paths didn't follow the movement of the globe. That was due to the paths being added to the `svg` but not updated along the country shapes on the `refresh()` function (added point 4).

To do so, the selection for these paths should be made available inside the `refresh()` function (it suffices declaring the var `flows` at the top of the script), and then adding an update for this selection inside that function. Like this:

```
function refresh(duration) {
  (duration ? feature.transition().duration(duration) : feature).attr("d", clip);
  // 4) Added the flows to the paths selection whose d attribute will be updated (only when present)
  flows && (duration ? flows.transition().duration(duration) : flows).attr("d", clip);
}
```

A complete version can be seen on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oscar_dr/0psy5udk/2/

Comment: Oscar -thank you for your input. Your answer is 90% there. The paths are now displaying correctly on the screen, and they have been correctly appended to the svg ... but they do not update once the user moves the map or zooms in and out. Could this be because you have used a different class to refer to them? Incidentally, I have used the the 'feature' class and it displays them correctly too. They just don't move around lol

Comment: Incidentally, that's probably why you haven't seen them ... if you hover over China and then add them you will see that they are correctly appended to the svg ... they then just fail to update as the globe moves around

Comment: I think I know why they don't update: they are added to the `#body` element, according to the initialization of the var `svg`. Maybe using a `g` element to append all the country paths and then adding the `.flow` ones to this element. When I have access to a computer I will update my answer in case this message doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hello Oscar -I am not sure I follow but will give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Noobster, I updated the answer. I think it's complete now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear answer to the problem.